# Facebook: Combine Follow with Share

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-page, facebook-sharer

I just recently shared a news article of german "Spiegel" newspaper.

As I shared the link, on the bottom of the shared link appeared a **botton to follow** the "Spiegel" Facebook-Page.

Can you tell me how this is done? I couldn't find anything on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Facebook decides whether to display that button or not – it is not something you can influence externally.

Comment: And how does Facebook "decides" this?

Comment: Using their own algorithms …?